# Is there an AudioField in Django2?

Tags: python, django, web

I really want to add an audio file to the database but theres no field for it. I know there's a github repository on it but it's very outdated so I don't think it will work in Django2. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: https://github.com/areski/django-audiofield    Help doc is http://docplayer.net/47521464-Django-audiofield-documentation.html This may support to D2

Comment: That is outdated. It won't work for me. But I think using models.FileField could work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Link to [Django AudioField](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-audiofield/) and it seems to have been last built 6 months ago

Comment: By the Way this is my first Answer

Comment: Congrats upon this, but the field you suggested to be really old, it’s of 5 years ago according to the link you shared.